# CloudsimSDN Error while running example file given in github

Tags: java, github, cloud, sdn, cloudsim

**Command run:**

```
java -cp cloudsimsdn-1.0-with-dependencies.jar org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample MFF ../dataset-energy/energy-physical.json ../dataset-energy/energy-virtual.json ../dataset-energy/energy-workload.csv > results.out
```

**Error:**

```
Could not find or load main class org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.cloudbus.cloudsim.sdn.example.SDNExample
```

**Github:** https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsimsd.

**Working Directory:** D:\SDP\Try2\cloudsimsdn-master
[image: Working directory image]

**Implementation Process:**
[image: Image Method 2: mentioned in Github]

I implemented method 2 mentioned in Github for installing and changed pom.xml as well. I've run mvn clean install and the build was successful

**mvn clean install output:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 7.922 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-12T12:39:05+05:30
```

But when I run the Example simulation execution provided in Github I'm getting the "class not found" error as mentioned above